# Size of a Graph on android

Tags: android, achartengine

i'm very new to Android and AChartengine and i'm working in my project.

Assume i have a Layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/displayECG"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

</LinearLayout>
```

And in MainActivity.java i code like:

```
view = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, dataSet, renderer);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayECG);
layout.addView(view, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

But when i run my App and i got a graph, it very smaller than layout space. I want a graph, it fits with my layout, so how can i do that?

Thanks,

Comment: anybody helps me, please!

Comment: Give height as android:layout_height="matchparent"